# If $Z[T, u_1] \oplus Z[T, u_2]=Z[T, v]$ where $v=u_1+u_2$, then there exists polynomials $q_1(x), q_2(x)$ such that $q_1(T)v=u_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

I an currently stuck on (b)(i) of this problem.

[image]

I denote $Z[\alpha, v]$ as the cyclic subspace generated by $v$. The question wants me to show the existence of $q_1,q_2$ such that $q_1(\alpha)v=u_1$ and $q_2(\alpha)v=u_2$. I know I should construct them out of $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$, but I have no idea how to find a polynomial such that $f(\alpha)(u_1)=u_1$ and $f(\alpha)(u_2)=0$.

One thing I have thought of is the Lagrange polynomial approach, but so far, I haven't managed to construct such an $f$ from $p_1(u_1)=0$, and $p_2(u_2)=0$.